# Plugin not applying changes on ngFor directed div Angular 5.2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular5

I've been searching for the solution for a few days but unable to find one that works. The issue is that this div which has a class ish-container-inner, is linked to a js plugin which works only with this code below:

```
<div class="ish-container-inner ish-product">
    <div class="ish-main-content ish-pflo-gal ish-scroll-anim ish-2col ish-square ish-content-parallax">

        <div class="ish-item">
            <div class="ish-item-container">
                <div class="ish-caption-container">
                    <div class="ish-caption">
                        <span class="ish-h4 ish-txt-color9">Special Effects</span> <span class="ish-separator">/</span> <span>Ink</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="ish-img">
                    <a href="product-detail.html" class="ish-img-scale" style="background-image: url('assets/img/bniinks-003.jpg');"><img src="assets/img/bniinks-003.jpg" alt="Project"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

But as soon as I'll put *ngFor like below, it won't work. Even with ngIf present:

```
<div class="ish-container-inner ish-product" *ngIf="products">
    <div class="ish-main-content ish-pflo-gal ish-scroll-anim ish-2col ish-square ish-content-parallax">

        <div class="ish-item" *ngFor="let product of products">
            <div class="ish-item-container">
                <div class="ish-caption-container">
                    <div class="ish-caption">
                        <span class="ish-h4 ish-txt-color7">{{ product.name }}</span> <span class="ish-separator">/</span> <span>Ink</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ish-img">
                    <a href="product-detail.html" class="ish-img-scale" [style.background]="'url('+product.thumbnail+')'">
                        <img src="{{product.thumbnail}}" alt="Project"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have valid data at this point in products but the plugin is not working for these div elements. I don't know why. Without the ngFor directive. Div is assigned some stylings automatically which are changed by the plugin on scroll i.e.

```
<div  class="ish-main-content ish-pflo-gal ish-scroll-anim ish-2col ish-square ish-content-parallax" style="position: relative; height: 629px; margin-top: -99.5455px;" data-initial-top="0">
```

But if I put ngIf or ngFor directive. It doesn't work anymore and these stylings are not assigned automatically. Awaiting response :)

Comment: remove `[style.background]="'url('+product.thumbnail+')'"` and try

Comment: Not working. I think lazy loading the js should work. Shouldn't it?